# WSO2 Carbon error on Ubuntu Server 12.04 64-bit

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

When I try to run WSO2 Dataservices or other WSO2 Carbon servers, i got the following error:

```
$ sudo sh /opt/wso2dataservices-2.6.3/bin/wso2server.sh start
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.:
CARBON cannot execute java
```

Then I check the JAVA_HOME variable:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_35
```

And it is the correct path. The machine have installed Oracle Java JDK 1.6 64-bit and Ubuntu Server 12.04 64-bit.

I really appreciate your answer. Thanks!

Comment: have you tryed with a fresh installation of the ESB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are running the server as the super user (sudo) which is not required. However I think you dont have the JAVA_HOME set in super user environment.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I run withouth sudo I got the following: ` /opt/wso2dataservices-2.6.3/./bin/native/wrapper-linux-x86-32: not found`. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: have you given enough permission to bin. other thing you can do is, set JAVA_HOME in sudo enviornment

Answer (score 5):

You can use it like this

```
sudo JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle ./wso2server.sh
```